# specify dll locations in VS

Tags: visual-studio, dll, reference

I have about 15 projects in a solution, and all of them have some broken third-party dll references. How do I configure VS to look for dlls in one specific directory? I am trying to compile and link my project, but it doesn't work because projects have broken references to existing third-party dlls. My solution consists of C# class library projects and an ASP.NET web site.

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to run the application, not compile & link it, right?

Comment: No, I am trying to compile & link it.

Comment: Are you sure it's dll's and not lib's VS can't find?

Comment: @Luchian Grigore What do you mean? Those are DLLs that do exist, I can correct the references manually, but there are over 100 of them, so I don't really want to do it.

Comment: It turned out that I've updated the references manually. It is quicker  than finding the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You go from one project to the other and update the references to point to the new location.

If this is a third party DLL, you can [record a macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967.aspx) the first time you do this and replay it for each project.

Comment: I'll try to use macros, but I am sure that this is not the best way to do it. Delphi7 has a way of specifying directories where to look for DLLs, and I refuse to believe that VS2010 can't do that.

Comment: @Bogdan0x400 - What language are you using? You didn't specify.

Comment: My solution consists of C# class library projects and an ASP.NET web site.

Comment: @Bogdan0x400 - I thought you might have been using C++, where things are different. Perhaps this will help - [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx).

Comment: I've updated the references manually, but I've accepted this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If they are project references (and they probably should be), you should not need to (unles you have moved the projects)

Otherwise, create a third-party Lib folder (under source control) at the solution root folder, place your third-party DLLs in it and reference from there.

If you need to fix up references, download and install [VSCommands 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf) which has a very useful copy and paste references feature (among others). [Fix up for one project, and then simply copy and paste to other projects. Failing that, you would need to manually edit the .proj files, using Powershell for instance.]